# A common eigenvector of $A^2$ and $A^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that the eigenvector of $A^2$ is the same as the one of $A^{-1}$, where

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

All that I can find is that

$$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}, \quad A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & -1/4 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalue of $A^2$ is $4$, and of $A^{-1}$ is $1/2$.

I don't know how to do the rest.

*Edit

According to my lecturer's note,

$$(A-\lambda I)X = 0 \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} a-\lambda & b \\ c & d-\lambda \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

If I use $A^2$ 's eigenvalue which is $\lambda = 4$.

By using the note provided,

$$\begin{bmatrix} 4-\lambda & 4 \\ 0 & 4-\lambda \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 4-4 & 4 \\ 0 & 4-4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then I'm stuck here given what I know and what I've done is correct...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE! Please click "edit" and take a minute to see how the formatting is done, so you can do it yourself in the future.

Comment: Thx for the formatting.

Comment: Nice edit. You're a quick learner. :-) As for your question, you can get $y=0$ from there, and $x$ is whatever you want except zero (since $v$ is an eigenvector if and only if $\alpha x$ is one, for any $\alpha \ne 0$). This gives you the eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$, so you can check that it's also the eigenvector of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thx again~! You provided me with the answer that I'm looking for. I'm grateful to the others as well, you guys have provided me with the knowledge that I do not possess as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: The actual form of $A$ doesn't even matter. All you need is that $A$ is invertible. Then you have

$v$ is eigenvector of $A^{-1}\Leftrightarrow$ $v$ is eigenvector of $A\Leftrightarrow$ $v$ is eigenvector of $A^{2}$

One of the four directions: assume $$Av=\lambda v$$ then $$\lambda^{-1}v=\lambda^{-1}A^{-1}Av=\lambda^{-1}A^{-1}\lambda v=A^{-1}v$$

Note that $A$ being invertible implies that $\lambda\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you must show that $A^2v=4v$ if and only if $A^{-1}v=\frac12v.$ To find vectors $v$ such that $A^2v=4v,$ you must find the kernel (or null space) of $A^2-4I,$ where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. To find vectors $v$ such that $A^{-1}v=\frac12v,$ you must find the kernel (or null space) of $A^{-1}-\frac12I.$